# What is the difference between Sola Scriptura and the belief in a closed canon?

Tags: terminology, denomination-survey, canon, sola-scriptura, inspiration

- Does belief in [*Sola Scriptura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura) entail belief in a *closed canon*?
- Does belief in a *closed canon* entail belief in *Sola Scriptura*?
- What is the difference between these two concepts?
- Is it possible to accept one and reject the other? Are there examples of denominations that do this?

Related:

- [What is the difference between special revelation and (biblical) inspiration?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89281/50422)
- [What is the Biblical Basis for Sola Scriptura?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1332/50422)
- [How do Sola Scriptura defenders have a list of "scripture" since the list isn't mentioned in scripture?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89229/50422)

Comment: Good question. Up-voted +1. I assume that David (for example, and from his writings) believed in _Sola Scriptura_ but did not believe in a _closed canon_. Or, at least, until Messiah came. Which, I think, is the crux of the question : the Messenger of the Covenant, Malachi 3:1-3, whose is the last word.

Comment: It is certainly possible to believe in a closed canon and reject Sola Scriptura. The Catholic Church does this. See: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44339/is-the-catholic-canonized-bible-closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### About terminologies

The term "closed canon" can be a descriptive terminology or can be a doctrine.  A group that has a closed canon *doctrine* will choose a set of books and teaches that no books can be added / removed from the set.  For this answer I'll use "closed canon" as a doctrinal position.

#### Does belief in *Sola scriptura* entail belief in a closed canon?

Yes.  To understand why, let's remember that *Sola scriptura* is about the scripture being **the highest authority** to produce interpretations and applications of scriptures.  That means all other sources of authority, such as personal revelation, church magisterium, or even church council are *subordinate* to scripture.  Of course for this to work you will need 2 things:

- [Clarity / perspicuity of scripture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarity_of_scripture) so that ordinary Christian can understand.
- Closed canon, otherwise how do you know which are the books to be the source of authority?

In other words, to use the *Sola scriptura* principle you need a canon first, although it is **not** the *Sola scriptura* principle that formed or closed the canon (it's another process).

#### Does belief in a *closed canon* entail belief in Sola scriptura?

No.  Most obvious example is the Catholic Church whose canon is closed, but believes in Spirit-led Roman magisterium to interpret scriptures authoritatively.

#### What is the difference between these two concepts?

- *Closed canon* is doctrine teaches that there will be no new Biblically inspired books to be added and that none of the existing books in the canon should be removed.  It's about freezing the set of books that can be called 'Scriptures'.  All mainstream Christian denominations adopt a **Closed canon doctrine** after choosing their own set of books as the canon.  The precedent was the resolution after the 2nd century [Montanist controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montanism).  But Protestants decided to adopt a *lesser* canon for their closed canon, instead of continuing the Catholic closed canon, calling the Protestant canon the true canon.
- *Sola Scriptura* is a Protestant doctrine to *interpret* the teachings in the books of the canon.  So far only certain Protestant groups adopt them, most notably Lutherans, Reformed, and Evangelicals.  The canon used is the Protestant 66 book canon.

#### Is it possible to accept one and reject the other? Are there examples of denominations that do this?

As mentioned above, you can accept a *closed canon* doctrine but reject the *Sola scriptura* doctrine.  In the *[wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura)* there is a section describing the [*Prima scriptura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_scriptura#Prima_scriptura) doctrine which can be applied to the *same* closed canon, but has a different structure of authority.  Some examples of denominations using a *Prima scriptura* doctrine to interpret scriptures: Anglican, Wesleyan.

But since the Reformation (when *Sola scriptura* was born) denominations which accepted the *Sola scriptura* doctrine (Lutherans, Reformed, evangelicals) also adopted the *closed canon* doctrine, after creating the Protestant canon (66 books).  While other groups can use *Sola scriptura* with another canon (or even open canon), it simply doesn't make sense to use the same terminology since it can only confuse people (it's about branding).  In other words, by the very logic of why the *Sola scriptura* slogan was invented (which was to counter the authority of the Catholic magisterium and to disagree with the Catholic canon) made it inseparable from the Protestant closed canon.

Comment: `Closed canon is saying "no more special revelation to be expected"` - but I thought you said that 'special revelation' does not necessarily entail extending the canon (see your answer [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/89289/50422)), so how does a closed canon entail no more special revelations that **do not** extend the canon? Did you mean no more "biblical inspiration" instead?

Comment: Also, what about Nigel's example of David (or anyone who lived before New Testament times for that matter)? Could *they* have believed in Sola Scriptura?

Comment: I think Nigel was just illustrating the possibility of an open/evolving canon, with progressive revelation, in which you apply the same principles of *Sola Scriptura* to the revealed canon "so far". Obviously, future extensions of the canon would require lots of divine authentication, like the miracles, signs and wonders that authenticated the 1st century church.

Comment: Right, perhaps David could have been more fairly labeled as an adherent to *Prima Scriptura* over an obviously open and evolving canon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133711/discussion-between-gratefuldisciple-and-spirit-realm-investigator).

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Yes, indeed. _Progressive Revelation_ was necessary and an _open canon_ while it proceeded. Now that, in these last days, 'God has spoken _in Son'_ (Hebrews 1:2) that canon is closed and _Sola Scriptura_ operates within a known and finite scope.

Comment: Among [certain people](https://www.gty.org/library/articles/A231/prophecy-and-the-closed-canon-part-1) 'Closed Canon' would be viewed as a doctrine, not just 'terminology'.  But one could argue about the two _terminologies_ ('terminology' and 'doctrine') for hours and hours and . . . . .

Comment: @NigelJ Thank you for your feedback.  I clarified my answer accordingly so it refers to "closed canon" as a doctrine.

Comment: Thank you. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 2):

Progressive Revelation was necessary and an open canon ensued while it proceeded.

Now that, in these last days, 'God has spoken in Son' (Hebrews 1:2) that canon is closed and *Sola Scriptura* operates within a known and finite scope.

Thus I suggest it was possible (and very necessary) to hold both open canon and Sola Scriptura until Messiah came.

Thereafter, the one marked out by John the Baptist (the Messenger of Preparation, Malachi 1:1-3 who was 'Elias that was to come') as 'Son of God' and also marked out by a voice from heaven 'This is my beloved Son in whom I am well pleased' is also seen (by Mark) as the 'Messenger of the Covenant' (again, Malachi 3:1-3).

Once he is come and once he has expressed all, by his own lips and by his specially chosen apostles, there is no more to be said, the canon is closed and a curse issued to any who would think to add to it :

> For I testify unto every man that heareth the words of the prophecy of this book, If any man shall add unto these things, God shall add unto him the plagues that are written in this book: Revelation 22:18 KJV.

This curse is seen (by many) as extending to all within the 'book' of scripture as such.

For now, Christ is come and Christ has spoken and there is no more to be added.

> God, who at sundry times and in divers manners spake in time past unto the fathers by the prophets, Hath in these last days spoken unto us **in Son** (literal) whom he hath appointed heir of all things, by whom also he made the worlds; Hebrews 1:1-2 KJV.

It is my own experience that much of Protestantism (though not all) would agree with both closed canon and Sola Scriptura.